# Вывод -nan(ind)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

```
    int k;
    double z, result;
    printf("Введите данные");
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    getchar();
    scanf_s("%f", &z);
    getchar();
    result = pow(z, (2 * k - 1)) + log10(z + ((k + 3) / (0.1 * z - sqrt(z))));
    printf("%f", result);
```

Почему выводит вместо результата -nan(ind)?

[image: Вот пикча с самим примером]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат %f используется для  чисел с плавающей точкой типа float, а %lf используется для чисел с плавающей точкой типа double в scanf_s, однако в printf вполне может использоваться %f

```js
int k;
double z, result;
printf("Введите данные");
scanf_s("%d", &k);
scanf_s("%lf", &z);
result = pow(z, (2 * k - 1)) + log10(z + ((k + 3) / (0.1 * z - sqrt(z))));
printf("%f",result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А можешь ещё чекнуть, правильно ли я поставил скобки? А то у меня со знакомым получаются разные результаты вычислений

Comment: @Asmund, правильно

Answer (score 1):

Формат `%f` в `scanf` (как, впрочем, и в `printf`) предназначен для работы со значениями типа `float`. Вы же пытаетесь использовать его со значениями типа `double`.